# jquery plugin Autocomplete - not displaying results

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, autocomplete

I'm having a problem with the Auto complete plug-in. Here is my code:

```
    var autocomplete = {
       cache: {},
       xhr: {}
    };

   $('#header .search input[type="text"]').autocomplete({
      minLength : 2,
      source: function (request,response) {
         var q = request.term;
         if( q in autocomplete.cache ) {
           response( autocomplete.cache[q] );
           return false;
         } else {
           autocomplete.hxr = $.getJSON("/search/autocomplete/nous?ajax=1&q="+q,function(data, status, xhr) {
           autocomplete.cache[q] = data;
           //if( autocomplete.xhr === xhr ) { 
                response(data);
           //}
        });
        return true;
        }
       }
    });
```

When I'm writing something in the input ("Hello" in this case), I can see in the web developer tool that its returning a json array. So, I'm getting a valid response when the request is done.

```
 0: "hello kitty"
 1: "hello dolly and frieda"
 2: "hello ass"
 3: "hello there"
 4: "hello do you make"
```

It is doing the ajax requests but the results are not being pushed into the drop-down menu, it's empty. Any help is appreciated!!

Thanks!

Comment: is this a typo? `autocomplete.hxr`

Comment: What is the purpose of returning true or false inside the source function? It doesn't seem to be documented.

Comment: I'm actualy trying to debug someone else code, and that person is no longer here...But it's to implement caching to avoid redundant requests.

Comment: Everything looks good other than the `autocomplete.hxr` typo to me. However, if you are using a newer version of jquery, there is a better way of doing this. I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: omg you are so right, im declaring my var as xhr , and im using .hxr... oh god, that's why a second pair of eyes is usefull sometimes! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This answer is based on comments:**

This is how you could accomplish the same goal using deferred objects:

```
var autocomplete = {
    cache: {}
};

$('#header .search input[type="text"]').autocomplete({
    minLength: 2,
    source: function(request, response) {
        var q = request.term;
        if (!autocomplete.cache[q]) {
            autocomplete.cache[q] = $.getJSON("/search/autocomplete/nous?ajax=1&q=" + q);
        }
        autocomplete.cache[q].done(response).fail(function(x,y,z){
            alert(x.responseText + "\n-----\n" + y + "\n" + z);
        });       
    }
});
```

Edit: looks like the reason the original code wouldn't work was due to the typo.

Edit2: added fail handler

Comment: Ok. seems that the typo did not fix the problem, im getting the same results; an empty drop-down. I also tried your code, same result. Any other thoughts?

Comment: Hmm... Keep in mind my code requires a newer version of jquery, it won't work in jquery 1.4.4 or older.

Comment: No problem. I simplified it a bit more too.